# Why am I having an issue passing an integer into a mysql query using a php variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am running a php function with this line in it:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `user-table` SET `$field` = '$value' WHERE `user_id` = $user_id");
```

For some reason this is not working. I have echoed out the `$user_id` variable, taken that integer and placed it in place of the variable in the query, so it looks like this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `user-table` SET `$field` = '$value' WHERE `user_id` = 11");
```

And it updated fine! So the issue must be something to do with the variable, but I can't figure out what.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure $user_id has the expected value at the time you put it in the query?

Comment: Yes, I echoed it right before and after the line where a I passed it into the query and it came out as 11 on both ends.

Comment: Alright, I take that back. You were right, I feel like a chump now. I was echoing too many variables, out of frustratioin, trying to find the issue and ended up missing the obvious. The variable I was passing through for `$user_id` was undefined. I must have been tired because I looked for this exact issue and missed it. Thanks! If you would like to be awarded the answer just post your response as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was accidentally passing an undefined variable thinking it was an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It can depend on the settings in your php.ini.  I can't remember the name of the environment variable, but if you build the string like so:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `user-table` SET `$field` = '".$value."' WHERE `user_id` = ".$user_id.";");
```

It should work regardless of your php.ini settings, assuming you've already escaped your $value, and are sure your $user_id is an integer.

Comment: Nice to see someone else going for the good old concatenation. There's no need to bail out of the "" to render the $user_id as integers aren't required to be quoted and should not be. They should however be cast as integers: "... = (int)$user_id ..." for instance. This is a simple but must have barrier in protecting against sql injection. Please see my answer above - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17375990/1353296

Answer (score 0):

If you are assigning both the *field* (column) **name** & **value** to the variables **$name** & **$value** like that then;

1. field/column names aren't required to be in ticks. Therefore;
   **a)** Change " SET `$field` to *SET $field* & 
   **b)** Change " `user-table` to *user-table*
2. Because you're quoting the entire sql statement, - "UPDATE..." - when you insert a
   **$variable** into a string and its required to be quoted, you need to escape the
   quotes or concatenate the string like:
   "... = '" . $value . "' ... ";
3. You should probably also use a mysql_real_escape_string() on your variable to avoid 
   most common types of sql injection like:
   "... = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "' ... ";

So, putting it all together, the following should work just fine:

```
mysql_query("
    UPDATE user-table 
    SET $field = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "' 
    WHERE user_id = (int)$user_id
");
```

Hope it helps!

Gez

Comment: Sorr, it keeps stripping ticks (``) from around the first occurrence of user-table and $field in both 1a & 1b.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But if this is the case then why does it work perfectly when I replace $user_id with a integer(11)? The syntax contradicts what you are saying and still works. Also, on a side I did run the variables through `mysql_real_escape()` and `(int)$user_id` also. So that is taken care of before passing them into the query.

I will try your suggestion to see if it works, but it doesn't seem to address the issue.

Comment: also, to stop it from stripping back ticks use a back slash like this: \`NOT CODE\` (Obviously you can't see the back slashes, but you can see the result)

Comment: Hi @moss are you sure that didn't work? I don't see how it can't have... Thanks for the tip on escaping (\') BTW! Hope it helps! Gez

Comment: I am sure it didn't work. There was nothing wrong with my syntax. Check in the question comments for what the issue was.

Answer (score -2):

If I remember correctly, you should wrap variable into `{}`, because in your example you actually pushing `$user_id` as a string.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `user-table` SET `$field` = '$value' WHERE `user_id` = {$user_id}");
```